# How to delete items in array redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im newbie at Redux and Redux, so im trying get a simple todo list.
I've got array in the store. Its okay with adding, but when im deleting item see this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined 
>   at 
>   var items =this.props.tasks.map((item,i) => (this.props.deleteTask(item)} />)); 
>   in *ListTODO.js*

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App className="container" />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InputTask from './InputTask';
import ListTODO from './ListTODO';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <strong>TODO LIST</strong>
            <InputTask addTask={this.props.addTask} /><br />
            <ListTODO tasks={this.props.store} deleteTask={this.props.deleteTask} />
        </div>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        store: state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addTask: (task) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_LIST', payload: task })
        },
        deleteTask: (task) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_TASK', payload: task })
        }
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps)
    (App);
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = ["task1", "task2"];

export default function todoList(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_LIST':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.payload
            ];
        case 'DELETE_TASK':
            console.log("DELETING", (action.payload))
            return
            state.filter(element => element !== action.payload);
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

**ListTODO.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 class ListTODO extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

     render() {
          console.log("LIST TODO:"+ this.props.tasks);
          var items =this.props.tasks.map((item,i) => (<TodoItem item={item} key={i} deleteTask={(item)=>this.props.deleteTask(item)} />));
         return (
             <ul>
                 {items}                         
             </ul>
         );
     }
 }

export default ListTODO;
```

Comment: You are actually mapping your `state` to the `store` prop, so I think it's obvious that if you change `this.props.tasks.map` to `this.props.store.map` will fix the issue.

Comment: In App.js sending store like tasks `tasks={this.props.store}`
And yes, error appear when im trying to delete item

Comment: Do you really have a new line just after `return` in the `DELETE_TASK`?! That might case issues...

Comment: Oh wow, its a really was new line. This fix the issue. Thanks very much, CD!